# How to restrict specific commands (example "kill") in Linux for specific local user

Tags: linux

How to restrict specific commands (for example "kill") in Linux for the specific local user?

Comment: The "StackOverflow" web site is for questions about programming only. "Programming" means writing computer programs. Questions about using operating systems can be posted to the "[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)" web site; questions about Linux can be posted to "[Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)". You can log in to all web sites of the "StackExchange" network (including those two sites) with your StackOverflow account.

Comment: Using `kill` a user can only terminate his own processes; a user cannot terminate processes of other users using `kill`. On the other hand, you have no possibility to forbid a user to terminate his own processes. You *might* replace `/bin/kill` by an own implementation; however, this would be a lot of work and users might simply circumvent this by installing the original `/bin/kill` file (in a different directory) on the computer.

Comment: Rename the kill command and replace it with a script that do the checks.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to restrict the "kill" command.

### this is not possible.

(unless you patch then recompile your Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/); see also [kernelnewbies.org](https://kernelnewbies.org/); another possibility might be to code your own [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) - see also [chsh(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) and [passwd(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) - or patch and improve an existing open source shell such as [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [zsh](https://zsh.org/) to forbid using the [kill(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) command. Be then however aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)).

As documented, the [kill(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) command uses the [kill(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) system call. Read also of course [sigaction(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Any advanced Linux user could download or recompile (using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) his equivalent of the [kill(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) command (or use e.g. some interpreter like [Python](https://python.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) doing so). You might configure his/her [`$PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (see [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and [exec(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)...) to make more difficult the accidental use of the [kill(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) command, but there is [*No silver bullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet) since your user could run `/bin/kill` in his/her terminal. Read also a good [operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).

Look for inspiration into the source code of *existing* open source software (also use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand their dynamic behavior), such as [Qt](https://qt.io/), [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/),
[RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), etc and many others on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/).

So you need to design your solution in the dual way: properly implement (perhaps with [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) used with [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...) a good enough signal handler.

Read also [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html),  [namespaces(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html), [pid_namespaces(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html), [capabilities(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) and consider using *carefully* [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques in your software stack.

Comment: Thanks @Basile Starynkevitch ,, it is really helpful